# JQuery - Checkbox not returning correct value for "checked"

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the checkbox, i've put a function that will add on the checked property dynamically as below

```
if ($(_this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $(_this).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
else if ($(_this).prop("checked") == false) {
    $(_this).removeAttr('checked');
}
```

when it shows the below as the property for the checkbox

```
<center><input onclick=\"CheckboxIsChecked(this)\" type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\"></center>
```

but when a function catch whether there is the checked property in the element as below. it would always return a false. What is wrong with my code?

`$(List[i].Checkbox).prop("checked") ? true : false`

Comment: What is `ParameterData[i].Maintain_flag`? Is it a string, or is it a DOM object (and if so, how does it get its value)? Other than that, `.prop("checked")` already returns true or false, so you can remove the `?:` operator.

Comment: @PeterB those are the list and the checkbox of the list items. it return a "undefined value" if I didnt use the ? true:false.

Comment: Probably this will help [Setting “checked” for a checkbox with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Please do `console.log($(List[i].Checkbox)[0].tagName);
console.log($(List[i].Checkbox)[0].type)` and share the result with us. It should print `INPUT` and then `checkbox`. If it doesn't, then your objects do not contain what you say they contain. It will also help if you show us the code that sets all the `List[i].Checkbox` values.

Comment: @PeterB for `console.log($(List[i].Checkbox)[0].tagName);` it output `center` while `console.log($(List[i].Checkbox)[0].type)` output an `undefined`  its innerHTML is `<input onclick=\"CheckboxIsChecked(this)\" type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\">`

Comment: There is your answer: the items in your list are not the checkboxes, they are the `<center>` elements that contain the checkboxes.

Comment: so that would mean my checkbox has 2 tagnames, 'center' and 'input' right? can i get to select the items based on their tagname?

Comment: @PeterB I deleted the center tagname and it works fine now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is(":checked")` to determine whether checkbox is checked or not:

```js
function CheckboxIsChecked(elem) {
  console.log($(elem).is(":checked"));
  return $(elem).is(":checked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><input onclick="CheckboxIsChecked(this)" type="checkbox"></center>
```

Comment: i tried is(":checked") before but it still does not work for me.